# UFT not showing the correct response but same is working in SOAP 4.5

Tags: uft-api

i am new to UFT API tool.

I am using the API with authenticate  which i can able to provide in SOAP 4.5 in Auth tab. 
Please let me know where i can provide the Auth in UFT. 
Because of this i could not get the response as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I found Solution in API

1. Import wsdl file into UFT.
2. Drag the request xml from wsdl file to test flow.
3. Right click and `properties` → click on the lock symbol.
4. Click `edit proxy settings` and there check `preemptive` to *on* and set username and password.